# Why is document.getElementById() returning null when there is an element with that Id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to build a navbar in React that has a child component `Menu` that renders one of two different versions of the menu depending on the width on the div that the Menu is rendered inside.  There is also a logo and company name that take up a relatively constant amount of width in the navbar and the div that holds the menu grows and shrinks to adjust for screen width and aspect ratio changes.  Anyway, that div that grows and shrinks I gave an `id="menu-section"` so that I could use `document.getElementById("menu-section").offsetWidth;` to grab the available width and use that in the function that decided which version of the menu to render.  The trouble is I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null`.  Why would the `document.getElementById("menu-section")` be failing to find the div and returning null?

```
function Menu(props) {
    let availableWidthPx = document.getElementById("menu-section").offsetWidth;
    if (availableWidthPx > 600) {
        return expanded version;
    }
    return collapsed version
}

function Navbar(props) {
    render(){
        return (
            <nav className="navbar">
                ...
                <div id="menu-section">
                    <Menu />
                </div> 
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the DOM is not loaded yet. Here's how to fix it:

```
function Menu(props) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let availableWidthPx = document.getElementById("menu-section");
    if (availableWidthPx) {
      console.log(availableWidthPx.offsetWidth);
    }

  }, [])

 return <div>Hello</div>;
}
```

Also, your `Navbar` functional component needs just `return`, not `render`

Comment: That was very helpful and but I need to be able to use availableWidthPx outside the call to React.useEffect()...  where the return statement is.  So I took `let availableWidthPx` out and declared it 0 before the call to  React.useEffect() and then tried to reassign its value inside React.useEffect() and it worked as far as the console.log() is concerned but outside that method it retained the value 0.

Answer (score 1):

Because there *isn't* an element with that ID until all the rendering has **finished** and the result added to the DOM … but you are trying to call it from the render method.

Answer (score 0):

Function `Navbar` doesn't add anything to the DOM.

Comment: Good catch, I wasn't aware of this syntax. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider calling the Menu function after rendering, or define it in an `afterRender()` block.