# How do I get useEffect to only run once in React.JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reload

I am creating an application where the login button will disappear/reappear upon logging in. However, the page doesn't update with the new classnames. This is my code so far:

```
useEffect(() => {
    try{
     //If token called logged in exists
      const loggedin = localStorage.getItem("Logged In")
      if (loggedin !== null)  {
        // Change display style
        document.getElementById("pfp").style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("NavLoginButtonpfp").style.display = "block"
      } else {
        //Keep Original
      }
    } catch(ErrorResponse) { 
      console.log(ErrorResponse)
    }
  },[]);
```

Ive tried window.location.reload but that just constantly looped. I have added a second parameter to the useEffect but it still loops.

I know its probably a stupid easy question but everywhere i've looked has just told me to add a second parameter

Comment: I prefer not using selectors in my react application have you tried creating a toggle and then rendering the content that should be shown / hidden based on that toggle value something like `const [loggedInToggle, setLoggedInToggle] = useState(false);`

Comment: The `useEffect` hook you have there has an empty dependency array, so it will run once on the initial render after the component mounts. What exactly is the issue or problem you have? Can you [edit] to clarify what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I found this answer that relates to this question and will help you if you decide to keep using `document.getElementById`, ([Why is document.getElementById() returning null when there is an element with that Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176501/why-is-document-getelementbyid-returning-null-when-there-is-an-element-with-th)).

I would advise as I commented which is:

I prefer not using selectors in my react application have you tried creating a toggle and then rendering the content that should be shown / hidden based on that toggle value something like

```js
const [loggedInToggle, setLoggedInToggle] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const loggedin = localStorage.getItem("Logged In")
  setLoggedInToggle(loggedin !== null);
},[]);

return (
  <div>
    {loggedInToggle ? /* content when logged in */ : /* content when not logged in */ }
  </div>
);
```